# C/C++: вектор нативного массива, как заменить элемент?

Tags: c++, массивы, vector

```
colors = new std::vector<uint8_t[3]>(5);

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    uint8_t rgb[3] = {(uint8_t)i, (uint8_t)i+16, (uint8_t)i+32};
    colors[i] = rgb;
}
```

Ошибка: No viable overloaded '=' ? Не понимаю в чем тут проблема и как это надо делать в С++

Comment: Ну не присваиваются массивы простым присваиванием...

Comment: А потому что не надо класть сырой массив в вектор. `std::vector<std::array<std::uint8_t, 3>>`, а потом `colors[i] = {(uint8_t)i, (uint8_t)i+16, (uint8_t)i+32}`.

Comment: Спасибо. Не так давно вернулся на С++, после 20+ летнего перерыва, ещё осваиваю "нововведения".. не понятно только, если это обертка, то почему напрямую не работает? Загляну в исходники..

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка первая :

```cpp
colors[i] = rgb;
```

привело бы к ошибке памяти, так как `colors` имеет тип указателя на вектор, а `i`-го вектора у вас просто нет.

Правильно так :

```cpp
( * colors ) [ i ] = rgb ;
```

Вторая ошибка в том-что у типа массива нет оператора присваивания.

Есть возможность исправить эту проблему, обернув массив в структуру.

```cpp
# include <vector>
# include <cstdint>

struct  sRGB  {
  uint8_t a [ 3 ] ;
} ;

int main(){
  std::vector<sRGB>*colors = new std::vector<sRGB>(5);

  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    sRGB rgb = sRGB { { (uint8_t)i, (uint8_t)i+16, (uint8_t)i+32 } } ;
    ( * colors ) [ i ] = rgb ;
 }
}
```